# Angular- Cannot use namespace 'moment' as a type

Tags: angular, namespaces, momentjs

I am getting error when compile the code

```
import * as moment from "moment";
```

Compilation error

`ERROR in [at-loader] ./project/src/common/common.factory.spec.ts:72:40  TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'moment' as a type.`

Any suggestion, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import moment without alias.

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Also, you might need to add the option allowSyntheticDefaultImports and set it to true in your tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: allowSyntheticDefaultImports already there and import moment from 'moment' not helping throwing same error

Comment: Can you give me the complete error and your Angular and Typescript versions please ?

Comment: I had to restart VS Code to get rid of it flagging it as an error after the suggested change to tsConfig.json